# Polynomial ring $R[X] $ has zero Jacobson radical, for $R$ a domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative domain.

Prove that the Jacobson radical of $R[X]$, i.e. the intersection of all maximal ideals, is the zero ideal.

Thank you.

Comment: No need for us to prove this; somebody already did that. A searchfor "Jacobson radical" must certainly turn up something.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ f\in J(R[x])\Rightarrow f\:$ in all max $\rm M$ $\Rightarrow\:\overbrace{\rm 1\! +\! x\:\!f\:\text{ in no max}\ \rm M}^{\small\textstyle \rm 1\!+\!x\:\!f,f\in M\Rightarrow 1\in M}\Rightarrow \rm 1\!+\!x\:\!f\,$ unit $\rm \Rightarrow f = 0$

**Remark** $ $ More generally this shows that $\rm R[x]$ has Jacobson radical equal to its nilradical: the above shows $\rm\ f\in J(R[x])\Rightarrow 1+x\:\!f\,$ a unit, so by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83886/242) all coef's of $\rm\,f\,$ are in $\rm\sqrt R$ so $\rm\,f\in \sqrt{R[x]}$

Perhaps the following is of interest, from my [post giving a constructive generalization of Euclid's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2653/242) of infinitely many primes (for any ring with fewer units than elements).

**Theorem** $ $ TFAE in ring $\rm\:R\:$ with units $\rm\:U,\:$ ideal $\rm\:J,\:$ and Jacobson radical $\rm\:Jac(R)$

$\rm(1)\quad  J \subseteq Jac(R),\quad $ i.e.  $\rm\:J\:$  lies in every max ideal $\rm\:M\:$ of $\rm\:R$

$\rm(2)\quad  1+J \subseteq U,\quad\  $  i.e. $\rm\: 1 + j\:$  is a unit for every $\rm\: j \in J$

$\rm(3)\quad  I\neq 1\ \Rightarrow\  I+J \neq 1,\qquad $  i.e.  proper  ideals survive in $\rm\:R/J$

$\rm(4)\quad M\:$ max $\rm\:\Rightarrow  M+J \ne 1,\quad $  i.e. $ $ max $ $ ideals $ $ survive $ $ in $\rm\:R/J$

**Proof** $\: $ (sketch) $\ $  With  $\rm\:i \in I,\ j \in J,\:$ and max ideal $\rm\:M,$

$\rm(1\Rightarrow 2)\quad  j \in all\ M\ \Rightarrow\ 1+j \in no\ M\ \Rightarrow\ 1+j\:$ unit.

$\rm(2\Rightarrow 3)\quad i+j = 1\ \Rightarrow\ 1-j = i\:$ unit $\rm\:\Rightarrow  I = 1\:.$

$\rm(3\Rightarrow 4)\ \:$  Let $\rm\:I = M\:$ max.

$\rm(4\Rightarrow 1)\quad  M+J \ne 1 \Rightarrow\ J \subseteq M\:$  by  $\rm\:M\:$ max.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand the last implication. Why must f be zero if 1+xf is a unit? (BTW, I found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63851/intersection-maximal-ideals-of-a-polynomial-ring, but it's not helping more.

Comment: Hint: $\rm\: gh = 1\:\Rightarrow\: deg\:g = \ldots\:$ but $\rm\:deg(x\:f+1) > \ldots\:$ if $\rm\:f\ne 0,\:$ using $\rm\:R\:$ is domain.

Comment: This is what I understand: $deg(xf+1)>deg(f)$ and $g(1+xf)=1$ cannot happen unless $f=0$, since $R$ is a domain. Right? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: It's simpler if you follow the hint. If $\rm\:g\:$ is a unit then $\rm\:gh = 1\:$ for some $\rm\:h \in R[x].\:$ Since $\rm\:R\:$ is a domain, $\rm\:deg(gh) = deg\:g + \deg\:h = \deg\:\!1 = 0,\:$ so $\rm\:deg\:g = \ldots\:$ However, if $\rm\:f\ne 0\:$ then $\rm\:deg(xf+1) \ge 1 > \ldots = $ degree of units. So $\rm\:xf+1\:$ is not a unit, having higher degree than units. $\quad$

Comment: I had that in mind :) so deg(g)=deg(h)=0 and deg(units)=0, so the conclusion follows (f=0). Thanks again.

Comment: @AdrianM Yes, you've got it now.

Comment: why 1+xf is not in any maximal ideal?

Comment: @user297564 because if $f$ and $1 + xf$ are in an ideal then $1$ is too, so the ideal is not proper, in particular not maximal.

Answer (score 10):

Exercise 1.4 of Atiyah - Macdonald tells you that in any polynomial ring $R[x]$, the Jacobson radical and nilradical are equal. For your problem let us throw in the additional hypothesis that $R$ is an integral domain. Then the nilradical of $R[x]$ is zero because $R[x]$ is an integral domain and hence the Jacobson radical is zero.

Comment: Oh, great solution, thank you! I like it so much that I will present them both (along with the above, thanks to @Bill Dubuque).