# Jacobson radical equal to nilradical in $R[X]$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a non-zero commutative ring with identity. Let $\textrm{nilrad}(R)$ be the nilradical of $R$, which can be characterised either as the intersection of all prime ideals of $R$, or as the ideal of nilpotent elements. Let $J(R)$ be the Jacobson radical of $R$, which can be characterised either as the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$ or as the ideal of elements $x\in R$ with the property that $1-xy$ is a unit for all $y\in R.$

In general, the nilradical of R is contained in the Jacobson radical. I want to show that the reverse inclusion holds in the polynomial ring $R[X].$ Can someone please give me a hint for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153333/jacobson-radical-of-rx-where-r-is-domain

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the following elementary facts about polynomials:

Let $f\in R[X]$, $f=a_0+a_1X+\cdots+a_nX^n$. Then

$(1)$ $f$ is nilpotent iff $a_i$ is nilpotent for all $i\ge 0$;

$(2)$ $f$ is invertible iff $a_0$ is invertible and $a_i$ is nilpotent for all $i\ge 1$.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/153338/242) for a much simpler approach, a la Euclid.