# The intersection of the nonzero prime ideals of R[x] is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Theorem: If $R$ is an integral domain then the intersection of all nonzero prime ideals of $R[x]$ is zero.

The proof of this theorem(Kaplansky) in the paper by J Peter May but it is proved by using concepts of R-algebra and few more lemmas on it. I was wondering if it can be done in more simpler(elementary) way as alternative so that a beginner can understand it. Can any one please figure it out... Thank you

Comment: Funnily enough, I was talking to Dr. May as I read this problem, and I read him the question. He said, "if there was a remarkably simpler way to prove this, don't you think I would have proved it that way?"

Comment: Are you missing some assumptions?  For example, for the ring $R = \mathbb{R}[x] / \langle x^2 \rangle$, the intersection of all prime ideals (all of which are nonzero) is $\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: @Don Thousand -- Mathematics is full of theorems whose original proofs were far more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @Danial Schepler u can visit the page https://www.google.com/search?q=munshi%27s+proof+of+the+nullstellensatz&oq=munsi+proof+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i13i30.5189j0j4&client=ms-android-motorola-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @uniquesolution I know, it was a joke on his part.

Comment: If $R$ has nonzero nilpotents, this is false.

Comment: You forgot the crucial  hypothesis (in paragraph $2)$ "the letter $R$ will always stand for an integral domain". The proof is essentially the same as in Theorems $18-21$ in Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings*. All the proofs are very easy - a few lines  using only basic ring theory, and all obvious (except possibly his Theorem $1$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25740/242)), which is also  a few lines of simple algebra, along with Zorn's Lemma  - a basic result for localization). If this is not "simple" to you then please explain why, so we can help you past any obstacles.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153338/242) for one simpler way, a la Euclid's classical proof: $ $ if $\,f\,$ is "diviible by" (i.e. in) all max primes, then $1+xf\,$ is divisible by no max primes, so it is a unit, so $\,f = 0\,$ by $R$ a domain. $\ \ $

Comment: @ Bill Dubuque can u please elaborate a bit about Euclid classical proof I m not getting it