# Jacobson radical of matrix ring

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring, $S$ be the subring of matrix ring $M_2(R)$ consisting of upper triangular matrices $\left( \begin{matrix}
 a&  b\\
 0&  d\\
\end{matrix} \right)$ with $a,b,d\in R$, how to prove that

1. $J(M_n(R))=M_n(J(R))$;
2. $J(S)$ consists of matrices $\left( \begin{matrix}
    a&  b\\
    0&  d\\
   \end{matrix} \right)$ with $a,d\in J(R)$ and $b\in R$?

---

For the first problem, we know that
$$A\in J(M_n(R))\Longleftrightarrow AB=0, \text{for every simple left $M_n(R)$-mdule $B$.}$$

I want to show that all entries of $A$ are in $J(R)$, but i do not know what to do with "simple left $M_n(R)$-module $B$".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Sorry, i do not know what to do with simple left $M_n(R)$-modules.

Comment: The second question is handled [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2097740/29335) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2458902/29335).  I think the first question is also a duplicate, but I haven't been able to find it yet. Hopefully someone can help me with that..

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!